# Trying to test if a bit is set in a char value

Tags: objective-c, bit-manipulation

If have an array of char's pulled out of an NSData object with getBytes:range:

I want to test if a particular bit is set. I would assume I would do it with a bitwise AND but it doesn't seem to be working for me.

I have the following:

```
unsigned char firstBytes[3];
[data getBytes:&firstBytes range:range];

int bitIsSet = firstBytes[0] & 00100000;

if (bitIsSet) {
  // Do Something
}
```

The value of firstBytes[0] is 48 (or '0' as an ASCII character). However bitIsSet always seems to be 0. I would imagine I am just doing something silly here, I am new to working on a bit level so maybe my logic is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you put a `0` before a number you are saying it's expressed in octal representation.
`00100000` actually means `32768` in decimal representation, `10000000 00000000` in binary representation.

Try

```
int bitIsSet = firstBytes[0] & 32;
```

or

```
int bitIsSet = firstBytes[0] & 0x20;
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I knew it would be something simple. That worked!